# nc (netcat) hangs, waiting for more data, in UDP mode.

Tags: shell, netcat, statsd

I'm trying to send a small string to statsd via nc inside of a read block:

```
while read line; do
    printf "folder.counter:value|1c" | nc -q 0 -u $host $port
done
```

Unfortunately, when in UDP mode, nc seems to want to wait indefinitely, even though I've specified `-q 0`, which the man page says will make the program exit immediately after EOF.

I've tried passing `-w 1`, but if the data I'm sending comes in at more than one line per second, the data buffers up, and I lose my real time stats (not to mention risking a buffer overflow of some sort).

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do with netcat, or am I going to need to write something in language which has a statsd library?

Comment: although it didn't solve yours, adding -q 0 solved my issue

Comment: This happens in TCP mode now, which is what brought me here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up fixing the problem by switching to `socat`:

```
while read line; do
    printf "folder.counter:value|1c" | socat -t 0 - UDP:$host:$port
done
```

Comment: As there's been no other input, and this resolved my problem, I'm marking it as the answer.

Comment: You could have added a 1 second timeout to netcat (adding the arguments -w 1 would have probably worked).

Answer (score 10):

You can specify 0 as a timeout value to -w, so it won't wait at all.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Zero timeout is unacceptable, the error: `invalid wait-time 0`

Comment: @Astraserg no it is not, depending on what netcat/NC you have. Works in BSD nc.

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue; solved it using the `-c` option:

```
-c, --close                close connection on EOF from stdin
```

so something like

```
while read line; do
    printf "folder.counter:value|1c" | nc -cu $host $port
done
```

Yeah, does not really make sense to "close" a udp-connection - but that ended up working.

Comment: Adding `-c` solved my problem with `netcat (The GNU Netcat) 0.7.1`

Comment: Fixed my issue on MacOS.

Answer (score 2):

adding -v option solved my issue. The reason I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

For us, it was that we were sending an nc payload from one machine to another via a python script. In the python, when we explicitly encoded the payload in 'UTF-8', it just worked.